# Switching primary key from id to a combination of values in a pivot table

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to switch the primary key of a pivot table  from "id" to a combination of two values using a migration inside a laravel project. My `up` method looks as follows and it works fine:

```php
public function up() {
 Schema::table('gallery_image', function (Blueprint $table) {

  $table->dropColumn('id');

  $table->primary(['image_id', 'gallery_id']);

 });
}
```

However, when I declare the `down` method in order to undo the above changes like this:

```php
public function down() {
 Schema::table('gallery_image', function (Blueprint $table) {

  $table->dropPrimary(['image_id', 'gallery_id']);

  $table->increments('id');

 });
```

It first gives me an error `1068 Multiple primary key defined`, which tells me that the first line in the `down` method does not work as intended, but when I just run the `dropPrimary` line, it gives me an error `errno: 150 - Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed`.

I am not quite sure as to what I am doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following

```
$table->dropPrimary(); // without the parameters.
```

Or you could wrap the closure in the down method as following:

```
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0');
$table->dropPrimary(['image_id', 'gallery_id']);
$table->increments('id');
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1');

or 

Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
//code
Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
```

This will temporarily set the FK Checks off, and turn it back on afterwards.

#### EDIT

You could look into https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/migrations#dropping-indexes and try out the various functions!

Comment: Both approaches result in `Multiple primary key defined`. There are no other columns in this table than 'id', 'image_id', 'gallery_id'

Comment: I have updated my answer with a link to the documentation, you might need a different function (dropUnique() or dropIndex())

Comment: The `Schema::` part should be other way around, however, it has no effect on the outcome - I still get an error `Cannot drop index 'paper_print_template_paper_id_print_template_id_unique': needed in a foreign key constraint`

Comment: The only thing that worked was dropping the foreign keys and reinstating after you have dropped the index.